# Cleartext HTTP traffic to xxxx not permitted at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am just new to xamarian mobile application development. i have simple task to done just login functionality but i can't achieve the goal. i du the stuff as like in MainPage.xml

```
 public async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var vm = new LoginViewModel();
            //this.BindingContext = vm;

            
            string email = string.Empty, password = string.Empty;

            email = Email.Text;
            password = Password.Text;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                try
                {
                   
                    string WebAPIUrl = "http://smartentry.visitmydemo.xyz:81/App/SignIn?Email=" + email + "&Password=" + password;

                    //string WebAPIUrl = "http://smartentry.visitmydemo.xyz/App/SignIn";

                    //object input = new
                    //{
                    //    Email = email,
                    //    Password = password
                    //};

                    //string inputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        
                        Uri uri = new Uri(WebAPIUrl);
                        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

                        string json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                        
                        EntryClass MyEntry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntryClass>(json);

                        if (Convert.ToInt32(MyEntry.UserAccountId) > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(MyEntry.UserRoleId) > 0 && (Convert.ToBoolean(MyEntry.IsActive) == true) && Convert.ToInt32(MyEntry.ClientId) > 0)
                        {
                            //nevigate to dashboard page
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Login Success!!", "OK");

                        }
                        else if (Convert.ToInt32(MyEntry.UserAccountId) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(MyEntry.UserRoleId) == 0 && (Convert.ToBoolean(MyEntry.IsActive) == false) && Convert.ToInt32(MyEntry.ClientId) == 0)
                        {
                            //if login fails
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid Login, try again!!", "OK");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  await  App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Error :" + ex.Message.ToString(), "OK");

                }
            }
            else
            {
               await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "All fields are required", "OK");
            }
        }
```

and there is another implement to get access traffic true i just do this things

1. adds `[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]` to AssemblyInfo.cs
2. create one file res/xml/net_sec_conf.xml as like :

> ```
> <network-security-config>
>   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
>       <trust-anchors>
>           <certificates src="system" />
>       </trust-anchors>
>   </base-config>
>   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
>       <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://smartentry.visitmydemo.xyz:81/</domain>
>       <trust-anchors>
>           <certificates src="system" />
>       </trust-anchors>
>   </domain-config>
> </network-security-config>
> ```

3. and finally added this to AndroidManifest.xml in section as like:

> <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/net_sec_conf" ....>

please help me to out of this stucks...

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest file, inside application tag use

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: still that error comes

Comment: now in varient `Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to smartentry.visitmydemo.xyz/106.201.234.2 (port 81) from /192.168.0.26 (port 56842) after 86400000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT`

Comment: The current error is Timeout. It happens when server didn't respond in given time.  It can be because of weak internet. You can increase timeout in seconds.